# Side Menu override back button for specific cases

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I'm using https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu
And it's working ok, but, I wan to override the stack.

For example, I have the next flow?:

`HomeViewController` > `MyBusinessViewController` > `TheBusinessXViewController` > `Add CategoryViewController` > `MyBusinessViewController` (Again).

But, when I come back to the `MyBusinessViewController`, the `Back Button` is redirecting to the previous `ViewController`, but I want to delete all the stack and have the initial menu there (Like as the `HomeViewController`)
Is that possible?

To have a more natural behavior.

Comment: You can set the `viewControllers` property of the navigation stack when you are ready to navigate to the `MyBusinessViewController` again so that the `viewControllers` property only includes the two arrays (HomeViewController > MyBusinessViewController)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude `Add CategoryViewController` to the flow, we need considerer this:
After the `Add CategoryViewController` is completed, you want to have:
`HomeViewController` > `MyBusinessViewController` > `TheBusinessXViewController`

`TheBusinessXViewController` will be the controller to display, then:

```
let nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TheBusinessXVC") as! TheBusinessXViewController
        nextVC.id = self.idtruck
        nextVC.extraparameter = "StringOrInt"

        let newViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeViewController
        let sencondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyBusinessVC") as! MyBusinessViewController

        let customViewControllersArray : NSArray = [newViewController, sencondViewController, nextVC]
        self.navigationController?.viewControllers = customViewControllersArray as! [UIViewController]

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```